# Bootstrap 5 Carousel width getting doubled in flexbox ancestor

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

i am having the problem that with Bootstrap 5 Carousel inside a Flexbox it doubles in width (and pushes the other flex-items the side) when changing images. This does also happen when the direct container is set to display:block but some ancestor element is flex.

This is my Code (the carousel is copied from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/)

```
<div id="midbody">
        <Main class="carousel-container">

            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                            <title>Placeholder</title>
                            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text>
                        </svg>

                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                            <title>Placeholder</title>
                            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text>
                        </svg>

                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                            <title>Placeholder</title>
                            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text>
                        </svg>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </Main>


        <div class="aside">
            <div>
                <h2>something </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```css
#midbody {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: $screen_width;
    height: auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

.carousel-container {
    display: block;
}
```

I tried:

- setting overflow to hidden as suggested here [Bootstrap carousel: images out of div when sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395028/bootstrap-carousel-images-out-of-div-when-sliding)
- changing the carousel's container to: flex: 0 1 auto;

I haven't really found any duplicate to the question, so i hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best "bootstrap way" but removing the `slide` class appears to nullify the effect. The problem must come from the animation. You probably should create a [custom transition](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#custom-transition).

In the snippet below I have simply removed `slide`:

```css
#midbody {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: $screen_width;
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="midbody">
  <Main class="carousel-container">

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel " data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text>
          </svg>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text>
          </svg>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text>
          </svg>

        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>

  </Main>


  <div class="aside">
    <div>
      <h2>something </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```